# How to build image file for Banana Pi M1+ with the help of Yocto Project?

Tags: git, github, yocto, openembedded, banana-pi

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, initially I downloaded Yocto Project and set up its environment

```
$ git clone -b rocko git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky.git
```

Then downloaded meta layer for Banana Pi M1+ (meta-sunxi)

```
$ git clone https://github.com/linux-sunxi/meta-sunxi`
```

And added the meta layer into yoctoproject, also set in local.conf

```
MACHINE ?= "bananapi"
DL_DIR ?= "${TOPDIR}/../downloads"  
SSTATE_DIR ?= "${TOPDIR}/../sstate-cache/${MACHINE}"
```

And on building the image file it shows the following error

- [Configuration for build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYVON.png)
- [Error occured while build compiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUD0i.png)

Log:

```
$ bitbake -k core-image-minimal`  

ERROR: Task (/home/uroborostech3/poky/meta-sunxi/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot_2017.11.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'  
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2415 tasks of which 2414 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.  
Summary: 1 task failed: /home/uroborostech3/poky/meta-sunxi/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot_2017.11.bb:do_compile
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

I tried

```
$ bitbake u-boot -c cleanall
```

And

```
$ bitbake u-boot -c compile
```

but there is no change in the error.

Is there any other layer need to add for Sinovoip Banana pi M1+ rather than meta sunxi?  How to properly configure and compile image for Banana Pi m1+?

Comment: It fails because sunxi u-boot needs python-dev or python3-dev to compile sunxi-spl-image-builder. It seems to be related to this [PR](https://github.com/3mdeb/yocto-docker/pull/10). Do you use latest version of meta-sunxi, maybe it is fixed now?

Comment: You can look at this [patch](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/744927/) too

Comment: Yes i installed  those packages , but still getting the same error